# What is a single word for something that cannot satisfy?

Tags: single-word-requests

For a long time I didn't make the sublime distinction between *something that cannot satisfy* and *something that cannot be satisfied*, and so I used the word ***insatiable*** for both until I was just now revising an article I wrote where this line appears:

> Like a bit of insatiable gruel in Oliver Twist’s bowl.

What is the correct word to replace *insatiable*, because obviously it isn't the gruel that is insatiable!

Ps: I'm trying to avoid using 'unsatisfying' as I'm looking for a word that communicates the difficulty or impossibility that insatiable does.

Comment: *Unsatisfying* works well in the context you describe. Please elaborate on why *unsatisfying* is unsatisfactory to you, and outline the qualities you would like to see in the requested word.

Comment: user191110 - @Lawrence makes a good point. My hunch is that a meal of as much plain pasta as you can eat would *satiate* you (i.e. fill your stomach), but it would be *unsatisfying* as it is a very boring meal.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a word that communicates the difficulty or impossibility that insatiable does, except that it will relate to the thing that isn't satisfying rather than the thing or person that isn't satisfied. I don't know if that helps?

Comment: Are you distinguishing between 'not happy' and 'not full'?

Comment: The word *unsatisfying* communicates [that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397238/what-is-a-single-word-for-something-that-cannot-satisfy?noredirect=1#comment942939_397238).

Comment: It seems like *disgusting* is what’s called for in your example.

Comment: Unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words satisfy and insatiable both have the root word *[sate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sate)*:

> to satisfy (a desire or appetite) fully

Therefore the adjective meaning "does not sate" would plausibly be **unsating**. It does appear in some dictionaries (e.g. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unsating)), but it's not a common word.

Answer (score 1):

Given that *insatiable*, meaning "cannot be satisfied", could be interpreted as "cannot get enough", perhaps a suitable word would be **[insufficient](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/insufficient?s=t)**:

> 1. not sufficient; lacking in what is necessary or required:
> 2. deficient in force, quality, or amount; inadequate:

Answer (score 1):

Consider **meager** (or **meagre**, depending on the dialect):

> Of food or diet: scanty; deficient in quantity, taste, or nutritional value.  (OED)

Example usage, from [a review of a book on the Spanish Civil War:](https://lareviewofbooks.org/article/spain-hearts-adam-hochshilds-latest/)

> ... the despair of young soldiers in the trenches, infested with lice, surrounded by dead bodies, and soaked with rain and mud, trying to fight while sustained by a **meager** gruel of potatoes and dried beans.

The phrase "meager gruel" is somewhat idiomatic in and of itself, being used as a metaphor to refer to anything that may be unsatisfying.  For example, in [a review of the TV series *Alphas*:](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/television/2011/07/alphas.html)

> If there are any grown-up fanboys left in America—people who can bring themselves to admit that this summer's blockbusters-in-tights are **meager gruel**—then *Alphas* may have enough beta charm to see them through the season.